# Issue with the basic example to connect AWS Lambda and MongDB Atlas

Tags: go, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to make work my connect to MongoDB Atlas by connecting fram AWS Lambda by follong the tutorial on MondoDB there : https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/go/interact-aws-lambda-function-go/

But I have an error when testing the Lambda function.

After multiple test I think it's coming from the request collection.Find(...).

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type EventInput struct {
    Limit int64 `json:"limit"`
}

type Movie struct {
    ID    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`
    Title string             `bson:"title" json:"title"`
    Year  int32              `bson:"year" json:"year"`
}

var client, err = mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("ATLAS_URI")))

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, input EventInput) ([]Movie, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    collection := client.Database("sample_mflix").Collection("movies")

    opts := options.Find()

    if input.Limit != 0 {
        opts = opts.SetLimit(input.Limit)
    }

    cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{}, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var movies []Movie
    if err = cursor.All(context.Background(), &movies); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return movies, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

go.mod

```
module aws-lambdaexample

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.41.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/snappy v0.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.13.6 // indirect
    github.com/montanaflynn/stats v0.0.0-20171201202039-1bf9dbcd8cbe // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/pbkdf2 v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/scram v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/stringprep v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/youmark/pkcs8 v0.0.0-20181117223130-1be2e3e5546d // indirect
    go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.11.6 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220622213112-05595931fe9d // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 // indirect
)
```

lambda function log

```
START RequestId: 9b96311b-2211-4d94-82c6-3bc0f2fd00a2 Version: $LATEST
2023-05-10T08:32:29.025Z 9b96311b-2211-4d94-82c6-3bc0f2fd00a2 Task timed out after 2.00 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Post text not images.

Comment: Sorry it's my first post I am correcting it right away, thx for the advice

Comment: What is the error, timeout?

Comment: The collection is really big, opts.SetLimit should reduce this number to 3 elements as it is in the log but the value taken by opts.Limit is really different, I think it's the cause by I have a timeout

Comment: Finally it's not coming from the options.SetLimit, I make a mistake by not usig a pointer. It's the next instruction where it is making a timeout